# IF LEFT THEN REPLACE

Tags: excel, vba

I'm searching for a code that can do this
If a cell in column C starts with 41 then replace as '41 and so on the whole column.

I'm trying the code below but it only replaces from the 2nd instance to the last IMEI that is why I'm looking for a code which will update the 1st IMEI in the cell. By the way, in my cell there are multiple IMEIs that are separated by comma. Thanks for the help.

```
Dim Rng As Range

        Set Rng = ActiveCell
        Cells.Replace What:=",41", Replacement:=",'41", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
```

I expect the output of

`419123234456,419123133214,419938475433` to be `'419123234456,'419123133214,'419938475433` but the actual output is `419123234456,'419123133214,'419938475433` and the 1st IMEI will convert the last digit into zero.

Comment: Click on the cell and you'll probably see that the leading ' is actually there. A leading single quote has a special purpose in Excel. Excel uses a leading ' in a cell to communicate that it's text rather than a number. Can you use something else other than ' for your application?

Comment: you are searching for ,41, but at the start of your result is not ,41 but 41.. simply add ' at the start of your result

Comment: Peter Ksenak thats why im trying to find a code that will also put ' in the beginning of 41 because i want to get rid of that method

Comment: Tony M Its not there when i double click the cell after running the code avobe the first IMEI will be like this ###############

Comment: What about: `Rng.Value = "'" & Join(Split(Rng.Value, ","), ",'")`

Comment: If what you really need is the ability to split the string into the separate IMEI's, merely use text-to-columns specifying the columns as being text.  No need for any prefix character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will return what you want:

```
 Function preSQ(S As String) As String
   preSQ = "'" & Join(Split(S, ","), ",'")
End Function
```

If the function is placed directly in a worksheet cell, the SQ shows up at the beginning, in the worksheet cell, because it is passed as a STRING.

[image]

If you are using this function within VBA, to return the result to a worksheet cell, then you'll need to add the prefix character within your macro in order to have it show up in the cell.  However, it will display with two SQ's at the beginning in the formula bar. eg:

```
Sub modIMEI()
    Dim rg As Range, c As Range
Set rg = some_range_to_process

For Each c In rg
    If Left(c, 2) = "41" Then
        c.Value = "'" & preSQ(c.Value)
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the leftmost character in *any* cell is the `'` character, then Excel will not display (apart from in the formula bar) or print that character and also treat anything after it as pure text.

It allows someone to enter a string into a cell that starts with a hyphen for instance, without Excel treating it as a formula. It's also commonly used to force numbers with leading zeroes to display correctly.

To get your required result, you'll need to prefix the cell with a `'` and *then* `'419...` so your cell formula would look like this:

```
''419123234456,'419123133214,'419938475433
```

but would show on screen as:

```
'419123234456,'419123133214,'419938475433
```

When you come to read/test the cell contents though, if you ask Excel for the left most 3 characters

`left(range("A1"),3)`

the result is `'41` and not `''4`